# Angular 2: How to read a lazy-loaded Module's routes from within a Component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am developing an application which is separated in multiple modules, which are lazy-loaded. On each module:

- I define a set of child routes.
- There is one "base" component who has a `<router-outlet>` that loads the corresponding component, according to the current route.

I would like to have access, from that base component, to all of the child routes that correspond to the module, and their "data" attributes.

Here is a simple example. You can see it live on [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ohfg2s).

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'general'
  },
  {
    path: 'films',
    loadChildren: './films/films.module#FilmsModule'
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**films.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-films',
  templateUrl: './films.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./films.component.css']
})
export class FilmsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // I'd like to have access to the routes here
  }
}
```

**films.component.html**

```
<p>Some other component here that uses the information from the routes</p>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**films-routing.module.ts**

```
const filmRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: FilmsComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'action' },
      { path: 'action',
        component: ActionComponent,
        data: { name: 'Action' }     // <-- I need this information in FilmsComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'drama',
        component: DramaComponent,
        data: {  name: 'Drama' }     // <-- I need this information in FilmsComponent
      },
    ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(filmRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
})
export class FilmsRoutingModule { }
```

**Is there any way to get the data attributes of the child routes from within a component on the same module?**

I've tried injecting `Router` and `ActivatedRoute` into the component but none of these seem to have the information I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { 
    console.log(this.route.routeConfig.children);
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can read the route with router.config:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-films',
  templateUrl: './films.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./films.component.css']
})
export class FilmsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.router);
  }
}
```

There wont be lazy-loaded routes in it.